# iSSH alternative

Tags: ios, terminal, software-recommendation

I'm using iSSH application on my iPhone, mainly for VNC connections. I like its usage. But as I understand, this app is not in App Store now, and the development of iSSH was ended.

Could you please advise another SSH / VNC clients, which has the same usage? It would be great to see SSH and VNC features, like in iSSH.

There are some clients in the Store, and I checked famous RealVNC - I don't like its usage. Now I'm checking Team Viewer, but it's a separate app, which should be started on a desktop.

Answer (score 1):

[Prompt](http://panic.com/prompt/), by Panic, seems to be the best thought-of iPhone ssh client. It's not a free app, though.

Comment: It also doesn't do VNC. But it is a very good SSH app. Prompt 2 is coming very soon too. Panic submitted it to Apple, just waiting for approval.

Comment: Yes. And is there an app with SSH and VNC support. Also, I know about vSSH, WebSSH and some more, but they are SSH only I think. Or, maybe two separate apps - Prompt is for SSH, and what's the best VNC? I hope you've used iSSH and remember that screen movement is good there. I don't liked RealVNC because screen movement is not useful.

Comment: What anyone thinks about Remoter VNC - Remote Desktop by Remoter Labs LLC https://appsto.re/us/YVacw.i or Mocha VNC by MochaSoft https://appsto.re/us/MMh_q.i ?

Comment: I'm trying Mocha VNC Lite version now. It's not bad. One thing is that there's no remote cursor visible, green circle only. Msybe paid version has it.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out Reflection (free) which has both iPhone and iPad versions. Unfortunately, it has no MOSH support and doesn't do VNC but its a solid SSH client.

Comment: Still not available from the Canadian App Store.